# Is there a way to get the Type for a Column using package database/sql in golang?

Tags: sql, reflection, go

Basically, without knowing before hand what the resulting structure of a query might be, I'd like to query the database, and return a structure like this (json-y)

```
// Rows
[
   // Row 1
   [
      { ColumnName: "id", Value: 1, Type: int },
      { ColumnName: "name", Value: "batman", Type: string },
      ...
   ],

   // Row 2
   [
      { ColumnName: "id", Value: 2, Type: int },
      { ColumnName: "name", Value: "superman", Type: string },
      ...
   ]
]
```

Is there a way to get the Type for a Column using package database/sql in golang?

I'm suspecting that what I want to do is

1. make an array of interface{} the size of Column(),
2. then for each column determine it's type,
3. then fill the array with a pointer to that type,
4. and then pass the array to Scan()

Which is a little like this code example from [sqlx](https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx/blob/master/sqlx.go#L438), but without first knowing the Struct that the data would be populating.

Comment: This may be doable by scanning into an empty interface and then doing a type-switch on the fields. Have a look at http://blog.golang.org/json-and-go (JSON specific, but check the section on "Decoding arbitrary data") and http://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_switches . Also check out http://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Scanner for the supported types.

Comment: if the answer is good pls accept thx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to do it this way:

```
func printRows(rows *sql.Rows){

    colTypes, err := rows.ColumnTypes()
    for _,s := range colTypes {
      log.Println("cols type:", s.DatabaseTypeName());
    }
}
```

Comment: I accepted your answer -- it was the one I arrived at myself.

Answer (score 0):

Using database/sql? No (as far as I know).

But you can use [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23507765/2859806) for arbitrary queries. And `json.Marshall()` from the json package will use reflection to determine the right way to print a value, so you could have a structure like this:

```
type Column struct {
    ColumnName  string
    ColumnValue interface{}
    ColumnType  string
}
```

And then use `reflect.TypeOf(someVariable).String()` to get the type for ColumnType.

Comment: what? will `cols, err := rows.Columns()` give us the information? doubt it?