# Is Golang's SQL package incapable of ad hoc / exploratory queries?

Tags: sql, database, go

Based of the documentation, it seems the only way to get data out of a database in Go is using Rows.Scan(), meaning you must know the count and types of all columns at compile-time.

Am I missing something? How are you supposed to support ad hoc queries? Or even pull all columns out of a table that may change in the future?

Comment: Look at using https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx to decode into a map. From there you can iterate over the keys (column names) and take what values you need. Alternatively you can use the new `Unsafe()` method to scan into a struct that has a subset of the columns returned.

Comment: @elithrar can you provide the link for Unsafe method?

Comment: https://godoc.org/github.com/jmoiron/sqlx#DB.Unsafe @Inquisitive

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `sql.Rows` type has a `Columns` method that will give you a list of the result column names.  That can be used to determine the number of columns for unknown queries.

In the docs for the `Scan` method, it says:

> If an argument has type *[]byte, Scan saves in that argument a copy of
>      the corresponding data. The copy is owned by the caller and can be
>      modified and held indefinitely. The copy can be avoided by using an
>      argument of type *RawBytes instead; see the documentation for RawBytes
>      for restrictions on its use.
>
> If an argument has type *interface{}, Scan copies the value provided by
>      the underlying driver without conversion. If the value is of type
>      []byte, a copy is made and the caller owns the result.

So we also have support for scanning column values when we don't know their type: either in their raw form, or as Go types.

Putting these two together, you could do something like the following using the [`...` syntax to call variadic functions](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Passing_arguments_to_..._parameters):

```
columnNames, err := rows.Columns()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalln(err) // or whatever error handling is appropriate
}
columns := make([]interface{}, len(columnNames))
columnPointers := make([]interface{}, len(columnNames))
for i := 0; i < len(columnNames); i++ {
    columnPointers[i] = &columns[i]
}
if err := rows.Scan(columnPointers...); err != nil {
    log.Fatalln(err)
}
```

Now the `columns` slice should contain the decoded versions of all the column values for the current result row.

If you have extra knowledge about the table (e.g. expected types, or know the number of columns ahead of time), you could probably simplify the logic a little.

Comment: Seems to be exactly what I needed. Cheers :)

Comment: I'm new to Go, do you know why columnPointers would be of type `[]interface{}` and not `[]*interface{}`

Comment: `rows.Scan()` expects a `[]interface{}` (using varargs syntax) where each `interface{}` value's concrete type is a pointer. A `[]*interface{}` is a slice of pointers to interface values. A `[]interface{}` where each value = &column is a slice of interface values that contain pointers.

Comment: Right, and Scan's arguments are defined as `dest ...interface{}` so you can e.g. pass a pointer to an `int`: `*int` can be stored in a `interface{}` variable, but not in `*interface{}`.

Comment: This method gives me a `[]byte` for each value. Can the `sql` package know the types of the columns in the result set?

Comment: @OregonTrail: it depends on the driver you're using.  Based on the documentation, the driver should provide the value to you without conversion using the above code.  If you are always getting back `[]byte` values, then perhaps the driver doesn't keep track of the types.

Answer (score 10):

Found example code for go-mssqldb driver doing exactly this. Ref. https://github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb/blob/master/examples/tsql/tsql.go - code extracted below.
It works, at least, for this driver. However, it only uses the sql-namespace API so it will probably/possibly work for other drivers too.

**Given any(?) SQL select statement, it displays the resulting data rows**

```
func exec(db *sql.DB, cmd string) error {
    rows, err := db.Query(cmd)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer rows.Close()
    cols, err := rows.Columns()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if cols == nil {
        return nil
    }
    vals := make([]interface{}, len(cols))
    for i := 0; i < len(cols); i++ {
        vals[i] = new(interface{})
        if i != 0 {
            fmt.Print("\t")
        }
        fmt.Print(cols[i])
    }
    fmt.Println()
    for rows.Next() {
        err = rows.Scan(vals...)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            continue
        }
        for i := 0; i < len(vals); i++ {
            if i != 0 {
                fmt.Print("\t")
            }
            printValue(vals[i].(*interface{}))
        }
        fmt.Println()

    }
    if rows.Err() != nil {
        return rows.Err()
    }
    return nil
}

func printValue(pval *interface{}) {
    switch v := (*pval).(type) {
    case nil:
        fmt.Print("NULL")
    case bool:
        if v {
            fmt.Print("1")
        } else {
            fmt.Print("0")
        }
    case []byte:
        fmt.Print(string(v))
    case time.Time:
        fmt.Print(v.Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05.999"))
    default:
        fmt.Print(v)
    }
}
```